# something wrong with my HQL Query - java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm connecting to a database via ssh, the connection is DONE successfully but when i try to execute a query i got this error :

```
"code": null, "message": "Unknown column 'e' in 'field list'"
```

Below is my code and my query :

```
    @Override
public List<String> exeuteReceivedQuery(String queryString) throws SQLException {
    ConnectToDataBase();
    Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryString);        
    return (List<String>) rs;
}

    @GetMapping(value = "/{queryString}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getResults(@PathVariable("queryString") String queryString) throws SQLException {
    List<String> cmd = sqlService.exeuteReceivedQuery(queryString);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(cmd, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: In `"FROM Utilisateur u WHERE u.id = :param1"` where is the `SELECT */whatever"`statement ? Also describe what's not working, what's the desired behavior and the current one ?

Comment: in HQL we u can run Select queries and not using the "SELECT" , by wiritng directly " FROM table t WHERE t.param = param";

Comment: the desired behavior is the make a var that receives any SQL query , and then it will be executed with the methode ExecuteQuery() ;

Comment: Okay, doing Java myself for a long time now and never saw that so i was wondering. Add the desired behavior and the error in your question, not everyone will bother to read the comments ^^

Comment: i ,thought that i wrote what i wanted to do  : "But the thing is that I can not define a method that will execute any received request, like it will do the same job as an SQL editor, but only allowing 'SELECT' queries" this is the desired behavior ^^

Comment: True, still, i repeat myself, HOW do you know it isn't working is there an error ? if it's not working, what is it showing/doing then ?

Comment: sorry maybe there is a little misunderstanding, ^^' the code that i wrote works perfectly, i put it to show you guys how i'm executing my SQL queries using HQL, and now i'm working on a method that will receive a string that containes a SELECT Query and execute, doing the same job as an SQL Editor , ( receive query - execute query) , @Jayesh explained to me how to do it , you can read his answer to understant better what i struggle to do ^^'

Comment: Ho, yes i misunderstood your question, sorry for the waste of time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create seperate DAO for below functionalities.

1. Database Connection (Function which returns you `connection` object.)
2. `function ex. runSQLQuery` which can except parameters like (isUpdate,isSelect,isDebug,connection,queryString,params)

In this way you can get DB connection and query execution whenever you want.

If you want to make connection global then make it `static`.

I hope it helps!

Thanks.

Comment: yes, things are getting clear now :) thanks i will search for examples like this

Comment: Do you have any example of this ?

Comment: @CarlaDX https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc
You can refer this. Here a separate method for each function is given. You can modify based on your requirements.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: the execution of the query

Comment: Any useful Logs that you can provide?

Comment: "code": null,
    "message": "Unknown column 'e' in 'field list'"

Comment: It looks like that issue in your query.
Please update the question with your code snippet. 
It will be easy to debug.

Comment: Here you go, i updated both of the question and my code snippet :) hope it s clear enough to debug